# How can I use NodeJS for front-end in large Python application?

Tags: python, node.js, npm, node-modules

I am currently writing the front-end for a large python application and have realized that I would benefit a lot from various Node packages (I am currently trying to make it into a single page ReactJS application).

From my understanding though, in most tutorials, Node seems to be used for the entire application. In my case I just want the front-end. So my question is how can I do that? Do I simply do an npm init in the folder where my front-end JS files are and install whatever packages I need? If not, how do I do this? Is this even an appropriate use of Node?

Thanks

Comment: I have seen Django + AngularJS, but never saw Django + NodeJS. But you should try something firts, this kind of question is not appropriate to StackOverflow beacause is too broad

Comment: @TalesPádua I was suggested to use NodeJS due to the need of many npm packages (react, react-router, react-bootstrap, webpack, etc). I a currently trying right now and can't seem to integrate them. I also haven't found much while looking around online :( Sorry if the question isn't appropriate, I just don't know where more to go.

Comment: I understand you just want to use npm to download client side javascript (no real use of Node.js on your stack). Wouldn't something like https://github.com/kevin1024/django-npm be enough to easily copy all the downloaded javascript to django static files directory?

Comment: @dyeray that is exactly what I want! I took a look at it, but of course I am now having some trouble setting all of this up. I will keep trying and hopefully it will work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Node.js doesn't run on the frontend but on the **backend** - you can use Node **instead** of Python.

You can use Node to prepare/compile/build/minify your frontend code.

You can use `npm` **modules** on the frontend - see [Browserify](http://browserify.org/).

But you will not be able to **run Node on the frontend** - unless you want something like [repl.it](https://repl.it/languages/nodejs).

Comment: Clearly I got npm and NodeJS mixed up. Sorry about that! What I meant was using the npm packages for this python project. I cannot for the life of me figure out how. Even with Browserfy, how do I set that up so I can easily install and use the npm packages in my application?